# Finding a chromatic polynomial by polynomial fitting

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, latin-square, chromatic-polynomial

I would like to find the [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) χ for the n by m [rook's graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph) G<sub>n,m</sub> for as many values of n and m possible.  The rooks graph is also (a) the line graph of the complete bipartite graph K<sub>n,m</sub> and (b) the Cartesian product of K<sub>n</sub> and K<sub>m</sub>.

This is going to be very difficult in general since, for example, χ(G<sub>n,n</sub>;x) evaluated at x=n is the number of [Latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) of order n (which is known only for n≤11).  In general, χ(G<sub>n,m</sub>;x) counts a generalisation of Latin squares.  Moreover, G<sub>n,m</sub> typically has lots of edges, making the standard deletion/contraction computation infeasible.

However, if we find enough values of χ(G<sub>n,m</sub>;x) for small x we can simply fit a polynomial to these points to find χ(G<sub>n,m</sub>;x) itself.  For rook's graphs, it may be possible to find values of χ(G<sub>n,m</sub>;x) efficiently by generalising techniques used in counting Latin squares.

I would like to know if it is ever feasible to find a chromatic polynomial via polynomial fitting in some cases, that cannot be found using deletion/contraction?

> **Question**: Are there examples in the literature in which a chromatic polynomial was found by polynomial fitting small data points (which could not be found faster using deletion/contraction)?